# Can't connect MySQL to DMS via CA

Tags: mysql, ca, aws-dms

I'm having troubles connecting MySQL database as a source endpoint on AWS DMS.

Client sent me credentials (host, port, username, password) and certificates (CA cert, client cert, client key) and I successfully connected to DB with DBeaver.

I tried to import CA certificate in DMS and it did it successfully, but for SSL mode selected in endpoint (both verify-full and verify-ca) it gives me an error in connection testing:

> Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2026 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]SSL connection error: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

I have checked CA certificate with

`openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text -noout`

and it seems OK.

I also ran into this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-bucket-access-certificate-error/) which says that CA cert must be signed by certification authority, the client sent me self signed CA certificate and apparently doesn't know how to properly sign it.

Does anyone knows how to bypass getting CA signed certificate or to get proper CA signed certificate (if this really is a problem)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Client send me new CA cert which was correct.